# Xamarin Android sensorPortrait

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, orientation

I am using Xamarin and my app supports API 9+, but when I add this flag:

```
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.SensorPortrait
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'sensorPortait').
```

But when I change it to  SensorLandscape, it works.

I've read, that there is some kind of a but, but setting it to SensorPortait gives me error even sooner (int the IDE)

Comment: did you try [Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]

Comment: Yes, but I want to achieve SensorPortrait. Only Portrait works.

Comment: i have just discovered that this is a reported bug in api 9. it is fixed in api 16

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12935

Comment: So there is no way that I can set it to SensorPortrait?

Comment: i don't think so sorry, try userportrait

Comment: read this it may be helpful http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/

Comment: I've already read that and it wasn't as much helpful. But anyway, thanks for suggestions :)